# Remove Ace Editor absolutely positioned 'X' div (it messes up Drag and Drop)

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, draggable, ace-editor

I'm trying to use the HTML5 Drag and Drop API on a div containing an Ace Editor, but it isn't working as intended. The problem involves the ghost image that appears when dragging the element.

Normally when dragging an element, the ghost element appears underneath your cursor. But the HTML drag and drop API, at least in Chrome, will push the top part of the image down to make everything fit on the page (or something similar). Not sure what I mean? [Check out this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d65ugevd/). Drag the top one, and its image appears exactly where you'd expect. Drag the bottom one, and the ghost image appears well below the cursor. This is caused by the child div that is absolutely positioned within the second one.

So how does this relate to Ace Editor? Well, all Ace Editors have an odd `div` as their last element. I'm not sure what it's for, but it is absolutely positioned and has two absolutely positioned children, the second of which contains some number of the letter `X`. Does anyone know what that's for? Is there a way to disable it? Deleting it fixes the problem and doesn't seem to break the editor.

Need an example Ace Editor to inspect? Check out [this page](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about). The div containing the `X` looks like:

```
<div style="height: auto; width: auto; top: -100px; left: -100px; visibility: hidden; position: fixed; white-space: pre; font-family: inherit; font-size: inherit; font-style: inherit; font-variant: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; line-height: inherit; overflow: visible;">
  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
</div>
```

though it has a sibling and parent with similar `style`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That div is used for measuring font size, so removing it will break the editor when font size is changed.

You can set `editor.renderer.$fontMetrics.el.style.display = "none"` before drag and restore it after drop, but setting top to 0 doesn't seem to break anything so you can try asking them to not set it to `-100`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll likely mark this as answered here in a bit. Going to do some research on it first though.

Comment: Very awesome. This did the trick! Thanks @a user. I opened [an issue on Github](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/2240) about it.

Answer (score 0):

This seeems solved in recent versions of ACE, but I had experienced similar problem caused by some ACE layers with height set to 1e+06px. I solved it simply by setting their height to 0 when dragging by a CSS rule. It is at the cost of loosing ACE editor content visibility during dragging, but that is fine for me, because noone probably needs to edit the content during dragging its container. The CSS rule may be very simple:

```
.[some-dragging-class] .ace_layer { height 0 !important; }
```